# Volume of the coffee mug

Tags: 3d, volume

The inner surface of a radially symmetric coffee mug is described as follows: consider the portion of the curve $z=x^4$ in the $x$-$z$ plane that is below the horizontal line $z=1$; then rotate it about the $z$-axis to obtain the surface.

Show that the volume of coffee mug is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

I am not able to  see what will be the limit of the integral that I need to calculate. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine to cut the mug into slice of circle disc perpendicular to z-axis.
So the radius of each circle disc is x. Area is $\pi x^2$. The range of z for the mug is from z=0 to z=1. This is the limit you mentioned.

Then you can take integral.

volume = $\int^1_0 \pi x^2 dz$

Put in the equation $z=x^4$.

volume = $\int^1_0 \pi \sqrt{z} dz$.

And you can finish the rest and get the $\frac{2}{3} \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with cylindrical shells.

$\int_0^1 2\pi x(1-x^4)\ dx$